# Port error during installation and deployment of Galaxybase

Tags: graph-databases

During the installation and deployment, when running./galaxybase-deploy build admin --home/home, I encountered the following prompt: port 51314 is occupied or server start error: port [51314] is in use.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

I can't find out what other program is using this port, is there any other way to change out port 51314?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that the port required by the graph service is occupied by another program. This can be solved by closing that program, or changing the port of the graph service with the -p parameter just like the following image shows (only available at build). If this happens to other ports, you can still reset the default port using -p parameter.